# seting <select> color, FireFox 3.6.17 issue

Tags: jquery, firefox

this works in Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE9 but in FF it sets white color, WHY ??!!

DO HELP ME PLS

HTML

```
<select class="widocznosc">
    <option value="prywatna" class="note_0">prywatna</option>
    <option value="publiczna" class="note_2">publiczna</option>
    <option value="tylko dla grupy" class="note_16">tylko dla grupy</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.note_0
{color: #b59285;
}
.note_2
{color: #e7511e;
}
.note_16
{color: #6a89a5;
}
select.widocznosc
{border: none;
outline: 0;
background-color: #FAFAFA;
width: 110px;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){
        jQuery(this).css("color", jQuery(this).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
    }).change();
```

Comment: here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfxdX/4/) that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the class instead: 
Here is the code in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/oteyi5/4/edit)

The changed code:

```
jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){        
      jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").
      attr("class"));
}).change();
```

Comment: it works, but I'm wonder why previous code doesn't works in FF :], THX for help

Comment: Even i don't know why it's behaving this way. Upto now what i've found out is that in firefox `jQuery(this).find("option:selected").css("color")` returns `rgb(255,255,255)` or white. In other browsers, it returns the selected color in hex. Why firefox is returning white, that's the question.

Comment: may want to also add back the `.widocznosc` class in case you need to use that class later. `jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").addClass('widocznosc')`

Comment: Firefox is returning white because the selected option's text is white if you actually look at it...

Comment: but why it is white only in FireFox ??

Comment: @boris - wouldn't the browser turn it white by adding a class, not actually changing the css attributes? I mean that would seem to make more sense... However getting the class works...

Comment: @kralco626 the browser is not changing "css attributes"; it's just using a pseudo-class internally. But jQuery's `css()` in its getter mode uses `getComputedStyle` (except in old IE) which will take into account all sources of style.  It's not equivalent to `foo.style.color`.

Comment: @gidzior possibly the other browsers implement selected option color changes using a selection (which does not change computed styles) instead of using the `:selected` pseudo-class (which is what Gecko does).